# ordered bubble chart in R

Tags: r, circle-pack

I am attempting to draw a bubble plot in R.
I have a data frame df with several columns but there are 4 main important ones:

```
freq   Pass         col        mut
  20     P1     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
  30     P2     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
  40     P3     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
  10     P1     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
  11     P2     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
  12     P3     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
  50     P1     #4949ff  T_C_S_101
  30     P2     #4949ff  T_C_S_101
  20     P3     #4949ff  T_C_S_101
...
```

- `freq`: size of the bubble
- `mut`: type of mutation
- `col`: colour of the specific passage
- `Pass`: passage

After running the code below:

```
cirPack_cutoff <- df[df$freq > 20 & df$freq < 99 ,]
   
packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(cirPack_cutoff$freq)

data1 <- cbind(cirPack_cutoff, packing)

data1$col <- ifelse(data1$Pass == "P10", "#bfbfff",
                    ifelse(data1$Pass == "P5", "#7879ff", "#4949ff"))
    
dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing, npoints=50)
    
    
ggplot() +  
  geom_polygon(data = dat.gg, 
               aes(x, y, group = id, fill=as.factor(id)), 
               colour = "black", lwd = 0.3,  show.legend = FALSE, alpha = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = df$col)+ 
  theme_classic() +
  coord_equal()
```

Which outputs this image:

[image]

However, the circles in each passage are distributed randomly, I would like to distribute them in a specific order, which should follow the `mut` information. The three circle of P1, P2, and P3 in each type of mutation should be arranged on the same line.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Desired output

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the same line".  Your circles are currently packed a single concentric group and coloured according to Pass. Do you want to see a concentric group at each value of `mut`? Or should each Pass have its own cluster? Or should there be one cluster for each Pass and each mut? Perhaps add a sketch if you find it difficult to describe?

Comment: apologies for the confusion, what I would like to see is for each Pass a distribution of the circles of the mutations in a specific order, here I would like the circle in each  Pass distributed in a circle, so there are basically 3 concentric main circles composed of all the smaller circles of the mutation, I added a small example

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know the expected output for sure from the given description, but it sounds as though you want one cluster for each mutation. This would require running the packing algorithm for each mutation. The plotting code would be easier and more idiomatic if you mapped the `Pass` to the fill colour.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)

cirPack_cutoff <- df[df$freq > 20 & df$freq < 99 ,]

dat.gg <- do.call("rbind", split(cirPack_cutoff, cirPack_cutoff$mut) |>
  lapply(function(d) {
    dat <- circleProgressiveLayout(d$freq) |>
           circleLayoutVertices(npoints = 50)
    cbind(dat, d[dat$id,])
  }))

ggplot() +  
  geom_polygon(data = dat.gg, 
               aes(x, y, group = interaction(mut, id), fill = Pass), 
               colour = "black", lwd = 0.3, alpha = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#bfbfff", "#7879ff", "#4949ff")) +
  facet_grid(~mut) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

There was not enough sample data in the question to generate this image, so the data came from randomly sampling your example:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- read.table(text =  "freq   Pass         col        mut
                            20     P1     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
                            30     P2     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
                            40     P3     #bfbfff   A_T_S_12
                            10     P1     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
                            11     P2     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
                            12     P3     #7879ff  C_G_NS_60
                            50     P1     #4949ff  T_C_S_101
                            30     P2     #4949ff  T_C_S_101
                            20     P3     #4949ff  T_C_S_101", 
                 comment.char = "\\", header = TRUE) |>
  lapply(sample, size = 500, replace = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()

df <- df[order(df$Pass),]
```

Comment: cheers, sorry, as the original data input is complex it is bit difficult for me

Comment: but what I want to achieve actually it is not separate plots for each mutation, only one single plot where the 3 circles of the 3 passages for each mutation are aligned

Comment: I added an example graph output

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I'm still not sure what your graph is supposed to look like. You have drawn 12 circles. Are these supposed to be clusters? Is Pass along the x axis or is that mut? What is the y axis?

Comment: it is just  snippet of it , there should be an inner circle composed of circles of the first P1, plus a middle circle composed of P2 circles and an outer circle composed of P3 circles